# Eager to get reputation points

Tags: discussion

I see most of the contributors on stack-overflow are very eager to get more and more reputation points.

Can someone tell about the usefulness of having high points on this site?

Does it increase the chances of our hiring in a company? Or increase our salary. I don't see any company specifically watching over stack-overflow for employee hiring. They have their entry tests and interviews etc.